# How to make a multiline horizontal StaggeredGridLayoutManager with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some tags, and I want to place them this way so that the user can tap on them. (each brick has a tag in it)

[image]

The problem is that there may be many tags and I can't know beforehand how many lines I need. How do I implement this?

Comment: Do you want horizontal and vertical scrolling at the same time?

Comment: @UsmanRana Just vertical scrolling.

Comment: StaggeredGridLayoutManager has option to set num of cols , just set that and all items will keep adjusting in new lines, just like a GridView.
What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: @UsmanRana I have to use a horizontal StaggeredGridLayoutManager. And that option becomes number of lines. But I don't know how many lines I need.

Comment: GridLayoutManager has span size lookup callback method, You can implement that and setup the span size of items

Comment: You said you need "Just vertical scrolling" then use vertical Layout instead and numbers of lines would be auto adjusting based upon the no. of items. Set the no. of cols as you want in a single line.

Comment: @UsmanRana That would make it look like [this](http://imgur.com/a/Czt9V). Some bricks may have spaces in them.

Comment: You can set span size for that, or can handle cell width in its xml layout. No need to worry. But if you don't need horizontal scrolling then using horizontal layout is really a bad idea

Comment: @SamuelRobert So I'll have to calculate the space each brick needs?

Comment: @UsmanRana So I need to calculate how many spans a cell need?

Comment: you just set num of cols to 3,4 as per your will and keep view horizontal and try. I think that's all you need. Check it

Answer (score 12):

Google's new [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating the vertical `RecyclerView` whose items is horizontal `RecyclerView`
[image]

Comment: he just wants vertical scrolling ,not horizontal as well.