# which layout is like static position in HTML

Tags: android, android-layout

in Android, I have some views with same height and different unknown width, extract from database. I want to show them horizontally but at the end of layout automatically raised down, like HTML static position.

something like this image:
[image]

When I use Linear Layout or Constraint Layout views put in one line and not raised down. and in Grid Layout all views should have same width.
Maybe there is an attr in linearLayour or GridLayout that can make it easy, but I could not find it.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not with andoid Api . But provided by third party libraries [Flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout), [flex-box](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Comment: StaggeredGridLayoutManager will help you develop this layout easily.

Comment: thanks. not at my desk, checking now

Comment: @Nouman Ch, it seems be what I need,  thank you very much .
does it support in api15 with any library?

Comment: yes it supports api level 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a newer and better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353494/1532987)

Google's new [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) , the [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Predicate layout](https://github.com/rajandev17/BookMyDrive/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ggktech/bookmydrive/PredicateLayout.java) designed by me to add views with different widths, it will Automatically render the view to next line when it can't fit in same line.

**Usage**

Add above file to your project and wrap childs inside it.

Comment: it is what I really want, but what's the difference by StaggeredGridLayoutManager ?

Comment: it's more or less the same, it can support views of different height and width, but i guess above solution will serve your purpose